# ASP.NET Application Auto Login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I’m attempting to auto login users to an ASP.NET application hosted externally (not under my control).  The external app loads in an iframe in my .NET app.  The goal is to log the user into the external app using our company username/password,  and redirect to the external home page in the iframe.

I’ve managed to successfully log in from the code-behind.  The second response received after posting to the login page does contain the html for the home page so I know this works.  I tried recreating their front-end .aspx form and forcing a post after populating eventtarget and viewstate inputs with values retrieved from the first request to the login page in code-behind.  The Request Body is exactly the same as when I log into the site outside my app, and the same as my code-behind and .aspx form post.  But I keep getting a 500 error on the .aspx form post.  I think it might be related to the ASP.NET session id stored in cookies.  It's the only difference I see.  I tried to set the cookie of my page to their session id from the login page in code-behind.  However, using Developer Tools I can see my app cookie isn’t getting changed.  It makes sense that I wouldn’t even be allowed to do this.

Is there any way to accomplish this?  My app has 10 tabs, each with an iframe loading an external app.  I’ve been able to fake out the login for all the external apps except the ASP.NET.    Seems like I should be able to pull this off if it works in code-behind.

```
        string url = "httxx://abc.com/Login.aspx";
        CookieContainer myCookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.CookieContainer = myCookieContainer;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string srcString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // get the page ViewState                
        string viewStateFlag = "id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"";
        int i = srcString.IndexOf(viewStateFlag) + viewStateFlag.Length;
        int j = srcString.IndexOf("\"", i);
        string viewState = srcString.Substring(i, j - i);

        // get page EventValidation                
        string eventValidationFlag = "id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"";
        i = srcString.IndexOf(eventValidationFlag) + eventValidationFlag.Length;
        j = srcString.IndexOf("\"", i);
        string eventValidation = srcString.Substring(i, j - i);

        string usernameTextbox = "ctl00$MainContent$Username";
        string passwordTextbox = "ctl00$MainContent$Password";
        string submitButton = "ctl00$MainContent$btnLogin";

        // Username and Password
        string userName = "company";
        string password = "password";

        // Convert the text into the url encoding string
        usernameTextbox = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(usernameTextbox);
        passwordTextbox = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(passwordTextbox);
        submitButton = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(submitButton);
        viewState = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(viewState);
        eventValidation = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(eventValidation);
        submitButton = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(submitButton);
        submitButton = "ctl00%24MainContent%24btnLogin";

        // Concat the string data which will be submit
       string postString = "__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=" + viewState + "&__SCROLLPOSITIONX=0&__SCROLLPOSITIONY=0&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + eventValidation + "&ctl00%24MainContent%24Username=company&ctl00%24MainContent%24Password=password&ctl00%24MainContent%24btnLogin=Login";

        __VIEWSTATE.Value = viewState;
        __EVENTVALIDATION.Value = evenValidation;
        foreach(Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
        {
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
        }

        // Convert the submit string data into the byte array
        byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postString);

        // Set the request parameters
        request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Referer = url;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; CIBA)";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.CookieContainer = myCookieContainer;
        request.CookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
        request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        // Submit the request data
        System.IO.Stream outputStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        outputStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
        outputStream.Close();

        // Get the return data
        response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string rspString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //Response.Write(rspString);
        //Response.End();
```

.aspx form

```
<body style="margin:0;background-color:#ffffff">
<form method="post" action="httxx://abc.com/Login.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" runat="server" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" runat="server" />
</div>
    <div style="float:left">                
<h1>Login</h1>
<div id="MainContent_pnlLogin"> 
    <table class="Table">
        <tr>
            <td><span id="MainContent_lblUsername" class="Prompt">Username</span></td>
            <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$Username" type="text" maxlength="25" id="MainContent_Username" value="company" class="Entry" style="width:125px;" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="MainContent_lblPassword" class="Prompt">Password</span></td>
            <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$Password" type="password" maxlength="25" id="MainContent_Password" value="password" class="Entry" style="width:125px;" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <br />
                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnLogin" value="Login" id="MainContent_btnLogin" class="Button" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
</form>
       <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#MainContent_btnLogin").click();
             });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The first problem I see with this approach is that the server you're logging in may be in a different domain. So even if you programmatically create a cookie with the session id, when the web browser tries to redirect: it won't attach the cookie in the request because it belongs to a different domain.

Comment: It is in a different domain.  I'm not completely sure the session id cookie is the problem though.  That's just what I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the following code work:

```
    string url = "httxx://abc.com/Login.aspx";
    CookieContainer myCookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.CookieContainer = myCookieContainer;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    string srcString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // get the page ViewState                
    string viewStateFlag = "id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"";
    int i = srcString.IndexOf(viewStateFlag) + viewStateFlag.Length;
    int j = srcString.IndexOf("\"", i);
    string viewState = srcString.Substring(i, j - i);

    // get page EventValidation                
    string eventValidationFlag = "id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"";
    i = srcString.IndexOf(eventValidationFlag) + eventValidationFlag.Length;
    j = srcString.IndexOf("\"", i);
    string eventValidation = srcString.Substring(i, j - i);

    string usernameTextbox = "ctl00$MainContent$Username";
    string passwordTextbox = "ctl00$MainContent$Password";
    string submitButton = "ctl00$MainContent$btnLogin";

    // Username and Password
    string username = "company";
    string password = "password";

    // Convert the text into the url encoding string
    usernameTextbox = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(usernameTextbox);
    passwordTextbox = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(passwordTextbox);
    submitButton = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(submitButton);
    viewState = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(viewState);
    eventValidation = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(eventValidation);

    // Concat the string data which will be submit
   string postString = "__VIEWSTATE=" + viewState + "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + eventValidation + "&"+usernameTextbox+"="+username+"&"+passwordTextbox+"="+password+"&"+submitButton+"=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Login");

    // Convert the submit string data into the byte array
    byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postString);

    // Set the request parameters
    request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Referer = url;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; CIBA)";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.CookieContainer = myCookieContainer;
    request.CookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

    // Submit the request data
    System.IO.Stream outputStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    outputStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
    outputStream.Close();

    // Get the return data
    response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    string rspString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    //Response.Write(rspString);
    //Response.End();
```